# Can I change the name of App_Start folder to AppStart?

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api

I don't like the underscore convention in .Net folders and I want to rename the App_Start folder of new WebApi project to AppStart. Doing this can disrupt something?

Comment: Me either! But worse is the lack-of-convention all about with Microsoft folder names :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"WebActivator is a NuGet package that allows other packages to easily bring in Startup and Shutdown code into a web application. This gives a much cleaner solution than having to modify global.asax with the startup logic from many packages."*

If you use [WebActivator](https://github.com/davidebbo/WebActivator), which seems to be getting pretty popular, you might run into some difficulties. See David Ebbo's post about '[App_Start folder convention for NuGet and WebActivator](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/02/appstart-folder-convention-for-nuget.html)'. See the points under "**Please follow the folder convention**" on the GitHub page.

If you have a WebAPI project you may well already have a dependency on WebActivator - I had, without realising what it was - so my advice is to just leave well enough alone. Things are complicated enough already!